# Data attribute to multi array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I want to find a value in an array from a html data attribute. And to compare value for some parameters.

My data attribute looks like to this:

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="22" data-product_variations="[{"variation_id":"23","variation_is_visible":true,"is_purchasable":true,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_color":"black"},"image_src":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_4_front1-450x470.jpg","image_link":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_4_front1.jpg","image_title":"T_4_front","image_alt":"","price_html":"","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":0,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":"1531","variation_is_visible":true,"is_purchasable":true,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_color":"green"},"image_src":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_3_front-450x470.jpg","image_link":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_3_front.jpg","image_title":"T_3_front","image_alt":"","price_html":"","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":0,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"}]"></form>
```

My answer is to convert this into an array then to get `image_src` and `image_link`.

I start with this:

```
var variationIMG = $('.variations_form.cart').attr('data-product_variations').split('},{');

variationIMG.map(function (img) {
   console.log(img);
    if (img.image_src == "scr") {
        return img.image_src
    } else {
        return null
    }
});
```

But it doesn't works because I didn't success to split correctly the data attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is not properly escaped, so try

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="22" data-product_variations='[{"variation_id":"23","variation_is_visible":true,"is_purchasable":true,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_color":"black"},"image_src":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_4_front1-450x470.jpg","image_link":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_4_front1.jpg","image_title":"T_4_front","image_alt":"","price_html":"","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":0,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":"1531","variation_is_visible":true,"is_purchasable":true,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_color":"green"},"image_src":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_3_front-450x470.jpg","image_link":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/T_3_front.jpg","image_title":"T_3_front","image_alt":"","price_html":"","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":0,"backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"}]'></form>
```

then

```
var variationIMG = $('.variations_form.cart').data('product_variations');

var array = $.map(variationIMG, function (img) {
    return img.image_src
});

console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7f8Wt/)

Comment: Thank you! It works! About the html it was because of copy/paste... If I want to get image_src and image_link in each array (`["image_src":"scr1", "image_link":"link1"],["image_src":"scr2", "image_link":"link2"]`), what I need to do?

Comment: I get it : `return [[ img.image_src, img.image_link ]];`. Thank you for your help.